# Python pandas install issue on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pandas

I am using the following method to install pandas, but when executing import pandas, it is still mentioned error module not found, if anyone have any good ideas, it will be great.

BTW, there are message about upgrade, do I need to do anything here?

```
sudo pip install pandas-0.16.2-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Password:
Unpacking ./pandas-0.16.2-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas==0.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas==0.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas==0.16.2)
Installing collected packages: pandas
Successfully installed pandas
Cleaning up...

python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas

which python
/usr/bin/python
sudo pip -V
Password:
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: What are the outputs of `which python` and `sudo pip -V`?

Comment: Also, does running `/usr/local/bin/python`, then trying `import pandas as pd` work?

Comment: @MattDMo, posted my output for which python and sudo pip -V, appreciate for your further comments for help. :)

Comment: @MattDMo, when executing /usr/local/bin/python, it is said "-sh: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory"

Comment: OK, how about `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`?

Comment: @MattDMo, it works! Magic. But it is not very convenient to use the long command, any ideas to make it work for default python command? I ask this since I am also using IDE like PyCharm, which has similar issues (I think PyCharm is using the default python other than /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pyt‌​hon ).

Comment: I'm writing an answer now...

Comment: one more question: what's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @MattDMo, sure, here it is, echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: Actually, this will go better in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). Care to join me there?

Comment: Sure, let me join now. :)